# PHP websocket disconnect issue

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I've tested several libraries ([workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman) and [PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)) but in all cases I have the same issue - when I open clients page everything is all right, I have websocket connection with my server, but later it disconnects automatically in a few minutes or less. Is it known issue or is there any methods to handle it? Or should I simply implement some function to force recconection if websocket fails?

This is a code sample for **workerman**

Server `test_ws.php`

```
<?php
require_once '/home/ubuntu/workspace/workerman/vendor/autoload.php';
use Workerman\Worker;

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:8082");

// 6 processes
$ws_worker->count = 6;

// Emitted when new connection come
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection)
{
    echo "New connection\n";
    $connection->send('Hello from server');
};

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
{
    // Send hello $data
    $connection->send('Data from server: ' . $data);
};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function($connection)
{
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

And client `client.html`

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.com:8082");
        
socket.onopen = function() {
   console.log("Connected.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
   if (event.wasClean) {
      console.log('Connection closed');
   } else {
      console.log('Connection failure');
   }
   console.log('Code: ' + event.code + ' Reason: ' + event.reason);
};
        
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
   console.log("Data received: " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.message);
};
            
function send() {
   socket.send("Hello!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Workerman Sockets Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h3>Hello</h3>
   <button onclick="send()">Send Message</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So, at first I start apache server and then run my websocket script via console, websocket server starts fine. Then I open my client web page and websocket connection establishes fine too, but if I wait for about 1 minute or less it fails with no reason. How to establish permanent websocket connection? Any advise will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Server**

[image]

**Client**

[image]

Comment: Are you running the PHP script from console? Is there any output? Does server process quit or continues after you've lost the connection?

Comment: Yes, I start PHP script for websockets via terminal, it works fine with no issue. When I open client's page server recognizes a new connection and client websocket is connected successfully. But if I wait for about 1 minute or so then websocket connection drops without reason with error code 1006 :( So that server still working but client is not connected any more and from this point I have to catch this failure on the client side and force websocket reconnection or implement permanent websocket connection somehow. Look at screenshots, I've updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that it is known issue for the client in case of websocket connection (websocket idle timeout). From [this post](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/working-with-websocket-timeout/): "In case of established websocket connection, server or firewall could timeout and terminate the connection after a period of inactivity."

Comment: Actually, this method solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [this article](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/working-with-websocket-timeout/): "In case of established websocket connection, server or firewall could timeout and terminate the connection after a period of inactivity."

This is the solution!

Modified client's page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Workerman Sockets Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Hello</h3>
    <button onclick="send()">Send Message</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.com:8082");

        var timerID = 0; 
        function keepAlive() { 
            var timeout = 20000;  
            if (socket.readyState == socket.OPEN) {  
                socket.send('');  
            }  
            timerId = setTimeout(keepAlive, timeout);  
        }  
        function cancelKeepAlive() {  
            if (timerId) {  
                clearTimeout(timerId);  
            }  
        }

        socket.onopen = function() {
          console.log("Connected.");
          document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Connected.</p>";

          keepAlive();
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
          if (event.wasClean) {
            console.log('Connection closed');
            document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Connection closed</p>";
          } else {
            console.log('Connection failure');
            document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Connection failure</p>";
          }
          console.log('Code: ' + event.code + ' Reason: ' + event.reason);
          document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Code: " + event.code + " Reason: " + event.reason + "</p>";

          cancelKeepAlive();
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
          console.log("Data received: " + event.data);
          document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Data received: " + event.data + "</p>";
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
          console.log("Error: " + error.message);
          document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Error: " + event.message + "</p>";

          cancelKeepAlive();
        };

        function send() {
            socket.send("Hello");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help to somebody.